# Copy OS X from MacBook Pro to USB External Hard Drive

Tags: macos, macbook, external-hard-drive

How can I copy my OS X to an external hard drive, so I may use the USB hard drive to start up my daughter's MacBook?

Her MacBook will not boot up, but instead shows a solid blue screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a copy of your hard drive, try [Superduper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/).

Either one of these will create an exact copy of your harddrive to an external. Then you can [use the external drive to boot up the other machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948).

You can not copy just OS X to a hard drive and install it to another machine. You will need your original OS X DVD for that.